# SSIS Skip Non Consecutive Rows

Tags: csv, ssis

Is there a way to skip rows 1, 2 and 4 in a SSIS csv import? Rows 3 is the field list and 5 to EOF are the valid data.

[image]

Comment: I think you can achieve this by using two script component. First use the first to add a column with the row number, check [this](https://hansmichielscom.wordpress.com/2013/06/20/how-to-add-a-rownumber-to-a-data-flow-task-in-ssis-2012/). Then you can just programmatically filter the rows that satisfy your condition (other than 1,2 and 4) using the other script component.

Comment: Unless the field list is dynamic, why not just skip it also?  Manually define the import columns, then load the data.

Comment: Very good point.  It always the answers that are right in front of me....I will give cred if you post as an answer

Comment: You can also cheat with Eric's approach - Remove columns 1,2,4. Use that file to set the column meta data. Then update it to indicate no header skip 4 rows. #lazydevislazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can start reading the CSV from row 5 and un-check the option Column names in the first data row. As a result of which, all column headers will default to column alias like Column0, Column1,...,ColumnN.

Now you can use the Advanced Editor to rename the default column alias to your desired names. Always keep the ETL data pipeline as simple as possible. Script task and component is really useful but wicked. Use only when you have exhausted all firepower.